# Image slider won't work

Tags: html, css

Im trying to use an image slider for my school project. It works perfectly when i test  it in another .html file but when im trying to use it in my project i get a black background instead of my pictures...Here is my html and css code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700);
 #slideshow-wrap {
  display: block;
  height: 320px;
  min-width: 260px;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 12px rgba(255, 255, 240, 1) solid;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#slideshow-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#slideshow-inner>ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
  width: 20%;
  height: 320px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active {
  bottom: -46px
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] {
  margin-left: -36px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] {
  margin-left: -18px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] {
  margin-left: 18px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] {
  margin-left: 36px
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
  left: 0
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
  left: -100%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
  left: -200%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
  left: -300%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
  left: -400%
}
label.arrows {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 240);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
  -o-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
label.arrows:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
label.arrows:active {
  margin-top: -23px
}
input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2,
input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3,
input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4,
input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
  right: -55px;
  display: block;
}
input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1,
input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2,
input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3,
input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
  left: -55px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 {
  left: -19px
}
input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 {
  left: -37px
}
input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
  left: -73px
}
.description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 260px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
  z-index: 1000;
}
.description input {
  visibility: hidden
}
.description label {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 240, 1);
  position: relative;
  left: -17px;
  top: 00px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 27px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
  -o-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  z-index: 5;
  color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li:hover .description label {
  opacity: 1
}
.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~label {
  opacity: 1
}
.description .description-text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 230, .5);
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
  -o-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~.description-text {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="work">
  <div class="Jobs">
    <br></br>
    <h1 style="color:white;margin-left:10%">Here,see some piecies of our work!</h1>


    <div id="slideshow-wrap">
      <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked" />
      <label for="button-1"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls" />
      <label for="button-2"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls" />
      <label for="button-3"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls" />
      <label for="button-4"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls" />
      <label for="button-5"></label>
      <label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
      <label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
      <label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
      <label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
      <label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
      <div id="slideshow-inner">
        <ul>
          <li id="slide1">
            <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/images/2014/08/dunckelfeld-website.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100% ;" />
            <div class="description">
              <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-1" />
              <label for="show-description-1" class="show-description-label">INFO</label>
              <div class="description-text">
                <h2>DUNCKEFELD</h2>
                <p>Project Name:"Dunckelfeld"<a href="http://www.dunckelfeld.de/en/">Visit Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="slide2">
            <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/images/2014/04/devart-website.jpg" style="width:100%" />
            <div class="description">
              <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-2" />
              <label for="show-description-2" class="show-description-label">INFO</label>
              <div class="description-text">
                <h2>DEVART</h2>
                <p>Project Name:"DEVART" <a href="https://devart.withgoogle.com/">Visit Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="slide3">
            <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/submissions/2015/02/54ef5f5139507.jpeg" style="width:100%" />
            <div class="description">
              <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-3" />
              <label for="show-description-3" class="show-description-label">INFO</label>
              <div class="description-text">
                <h2>CRAFTED</h2>
                <p>Project Name:"CRAFTED" <a href="http://opl.craftedny.com/">Visit Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="slide4">
            <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/sites_of_the_day/2014/12/Volkswagen-electrique.jpg" style="width:100% height:100%" />
            <div class="description">
              <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-4" />
              <label for="show-description-4" class="show-description-label">INFO</label>
              <div class="description-text">
                <h2>VOLKSWAGEN-ELECTRIQUE</h2>
                <p>Project Name:"VOLKSWAGEN-ELECTRIQUE" <a href="http://volkswagen-electrique.fr/">Visit Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="slide5">
            <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/sites_of_the_day/2015/01/vitosalvatore.jpg" style="width:100%" />
            <div class="description">
              <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5" />
              <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">INFO</label>
              <div class="description-text">
                <h2>VITOSALVATOR</h2>
                <p>Project Name:"VITOSALVATOR" <a href="http://www.vitosalvatore.com/">Visit Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

And my CSS file: style.c
```

Any ideas? [original image slider link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider)

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nmtx8roc/

Comment: Works fine when you put it in a fiddle. Did you wrap everything in `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: I put the code you posted in a snippet and it works fine.

Comment: I know...and that makes me crazy! I'm trying to use it in my project and get nothing :(

Comment: I put this in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zd2dsdph/ it runs fine. My guess is that something else is interacting on the page that is causing this error.

Can you look in your javascript console for errors?

Comment: If you are not getting the pictures it will be the link to the images is broken on your other machine. or where you are testing it. You need to move your pictures into the correct folder or if they are online images make sure your machine is connected to the internet.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean when you try to use it in "your project".  What are the differences from posting in a snippet and putting it in your project.  Please elaborate.

Comment: the differences could be that he has conflicts inside his project. But yes, elaboration is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that in simple css**

**>  NO need of any javascript**

```css
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);


.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>Simple css slider</title>
    
    
    
    
  
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <ul class="slides">
    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked="" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-6" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-2" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-2" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-1" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-3" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-3" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-2" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-4" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-4" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-3" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-5" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-5" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-4" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-6" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input name="radio-btn" id="img-6" type="radio">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg">
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-5" class="prev">‹</label>
   <label for="img-1" class="next">›</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

 
 
</body></html>
```